# How to detect if a form is being submitted to external link in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

While submitting a form, if someone had changed the route to some external url (phising), then is there a way to show a message that some external url is being used?
For example, facebook shows a "Leaving Facebook" page with "Follow Link" and "Go Back" buttons when external link is being used. Is there a way to achieve this in laravel?

Comment: if they submit data to external link what harm here .? it is not `phising`

Comment: what about password security?